# How to view Facebook feeds only for liked groups?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I have lots of liked groups and I want to have a feeds or a list where I can view updates from those groups only - similar to friend list.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Scroll down on the left hand side you should see

[image: menu]

pages feed. From there you will get updates from liked pages and groups

Comment: And that is for facebook pages, not facebook groups, right?

Comment: It is mixed with pages feed and group feeds :-(